# Want to create dropdown list from another table in blazor server with sql server

Tags: sql-server, blazor-server-side

I already making my database table in my SQL Server.

The tables are:

1. [image: project table]
2. [image: task table]

Here's my **ApplicationDbContext.cs** :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ProjectModel> ProjectTB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskModel> TaskTB { get; set; }
}
```

**ProjectModel.cs** :

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string? ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

**TaskModel.cs** :

```
 public class TaskModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string? TaskName { get; set; }
    public int? TimerQuantity { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }
}
```

**ProjectServices.cs** :

```
public class ProjectServices
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;

    public ProjectServices(ApplicationDbContext _db)
    {
        _dbcontext = _db;
    }

    public List<ProjectModel> GetProjectModels()
    {
        return _dbcontext.ProjectTB.ToList();    
    }
```

**TaskService.cs** :

```
public class TaskServices
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;

    public TaskServices(ApplicationDbContext _db)
    {
        _dbcontext = _db;
    }

    public List<TaskModel> GetTaskModels()
    {
        return _dbcontext.TaskTB.ToList();    
    }
}
```

I already populate some project name in my project table, so when I create this page (project page):

```
@page "/bindingddl"
@using TestUntukDropdown.Data
@using TestUntukDropdown.Services
@inherits OwningComponentBase<ProjectServices>



<h3>Ddlbinding</h3>
<br />
<hr />


<h4>This is from table ProjectTB</h4>
<select>
    <option selected disabled="true">-- Select Project --</option>
    @foreach(var item in projectobj)
    {
        <option title="@item.ProjectName">@item.ProjectName</option>
    }
</select>




@code {
    List<ProjectModel> projectobj;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        projectobj = Service.GetProjectModels();

    }

   
}
```

The output is:
[image: output from table project]

I want to populate my dropdown list for my task table that refer to project table, so when I edit project name for my task, I can choose it from the project name in project table.

So when I click the dropdown of project name in my task page:
[image: output task page]

It populated from the project table's project name.

Here's my task page:

```
@page "/bindingddltask"
@using TestUntukDropdown.Data
@using TestUntukDropdown.Services
@inherits OwningComponentBase<TaskServices>


<h3>Ddlbinding</h3>
<br />
<hr />


<h4>This is from table TaskTB</h4>
<select>
    <option selected disabled="true">-- Select Project --</option>
    @foreach(var item in taskobj)
    {
        <option title="@item.ProjectId">@item.ProjectId</option>
    }
</select>


@code {
    List<TaskModel> taskobj;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        taskobj = Service.GetTaskModels();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, trivial grammar like capitalising I and starting your sentences with a capital letter are expected; if you don't put the effort into such simple things, it *can* mean that the users you want free help from won't give the effort back.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for let me know and make it better! will make it better in the next question